# upgrade pyimport to python3

Tags: python3, pip, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code on Ubuntu 20.04. I have read that Ubuntu 20.04 only supports python3. When I try to run python3 code it gives me a syntax error, but I believe it is because one of the dependencies is using python2.7. Here is the error I get stating invalid syntax with the single quote after {prg}'. Is there a way to upgrade the pyimport package that is referenced in the message, or am I missing something else here?

```
================================ test session starts ================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.18rc1, pytest-4.6.9, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /home/ryan/tiny_python_projects/01_hello
collected 0 items / 1 errors                                                        

====================================== ERRORS =======================================
_____________________________ ERROR collecting test.py ______________________________
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/python.py:507: in _importtestmodule
    mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py/_path/local.py:701: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
E: File "/home/ryan/tiny_python_projects/01_hello/test.py", line 21
E: out = getoutput(f'python3 {prg}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.7 is not installed in Ubuntu 20.04 by default, but it can be installed from the terminal. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-suggests python2.7 python-pip python-pytest
```

python-pytest has been dropped from the default Ubuntu repositories in newer versions of Ubuntu than Ubuntu 20.04.

For Python 3.x:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip python3-pytest
```

#### Example

The first file is the file which should be tested.

fibonacci.py:

```
def fib(n):
    old, new = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        old, new = new, old + new
    return old
```

This file will be used by 'pytest' to test fibonacci.py:

test_fibonacci.py:

```
from fibonacci import fib
def test_fib():
    assert fib(0) == 0
    assert fib(1) == 1
    assert fib(10) == 55
```

Change directories with `cd` to the directory that contains fibonacci.py and test_fibonacci.py.

Results of pytest:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.17, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /home/karel/Desktop, inifile:
collected 1 item                                                               

test_fibonacci.py .                                                      [100%]

=========================== 1 passed in 0.04 seconds ===========================
```

<sub>**Source of example code:** [Python Tutorial: Testing with Pytest](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_pytest.php)</sub>

Comment: I tried using the above commands but got an error ryan@AERO:~$ sudo apt install --install-suggests python2.7 python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I believe I read that you cant use old versions of python in Ubuntu 20, only 3.

Comment: Prove it to yourself. Run the command `apt policy python2.7` in the terminal. It won't install anything.

Comment: It says I have 2.7 installed, but that doesn't solve my problem, unfortunately. I tried running pytest using python2 and python3 environments, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had a clunky install of pip. I removed python2, pip, pip2, pip2.7, and pylint. Then I reinstalled everything and made sure it was for python 3, now everything works fine. Thanks for all your help!